# Core Data: Set relationship from query result causes memory corruption (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I recently updated to Xcode 7 and converted a working project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2. After doing so, I experienced very strange Core Data behavior often manifesting as memory corruption (e.g. malloc related bad pointers etc.).

Ultimately, I found that setting a "back pointer" relationship in a child Core Data item with a reference to Core Data item returned as the result of a query seemed to be causing the crashes. (That is to say, I no longer set this back pointer relationship and the strange behavior has stopped.)

Given the following Managed Objects where Subject is the parent and ContentItem is the child:

```
class SubjectItem: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var configured: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var friendlyName: String
    @NSManaged var fullname: String
    @NSManaged var isMe: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var position: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var profilePictureUrl: String
    @NSManaged var selected: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var source: String
    @NSManaged var subjectid: String
    @NSManaged var subjectname: String
    @NSManaged var sourceId: String
    @NSManaged var toContentItems: ContentItem
}

class ContentItem: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var createdTime: NSDate
    @NSManaged var itemID: String
    @NSManaged var owner: String
    @NSManaged var source: String
    @NSManaged var type: String
    @NSManaged var position: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var toCaption: CaptionItem
    @NSManaged var toImages: ImageItems
    @NSManaged var toSubject: SubjectItem
    @NSManaged var toVideos: VideoItems
}
```

Note the "back pointer" toSubject in the ContentItem object.

Subjects are saved separately, and before, Content Items. When Content Items are saved, I have a function that looks up the related Subject (parent) of the Content Item(s) (child) being saved:

```
class func findSubject(subjectid: String) -> SubjectItem? {
    let moc = getManagedObjectContext()
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: SubjectEntity)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "subjectid == %@", subjectid)
    request.predicate = predicate

    var subject: SubjectItem? = nil
    do {
        let subjects = try moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if subjects.count > 0 {
            subject = subjects[0] as? SubjectItem
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error finding subject")
    }
    return subject
}
```

The code that persists the Content item sets the reference returned by the lookup function on the Content Item. The function looks like this:

```
if let subject = SubjectItem.findSubject(owner) {
   let contentItem = ContentItem.createContentItem(post: post, owner: owner)
   contentItem.toSubject = subject

    // ... more stuff ...
}
```

There is a class function in an Extension of ContentItem that inserts the new object:

```
extension ContentItem {
    class func createContentItem(post post: Post, owner: String) -> ContentItem {
        let moc = getManagedObjectContext()
        let contentItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(ContentEntity, inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! ContentItem

        contentItem.itemID = post.id
        contentItem.type = post.type!
        contentItem.createdTime = post.createdTime!
        contentItem.owner = owner
        contentItem.source = MediaSource.Instagram.rawValue
        contentItem.position = 0

        return contentItem
    }
```

Removing the assignment of the fetched subject to the Content Item back pointer makes the memory issue go away.

UPDATE: I failed to mention that the strange behavior occurred when saving the ContentItem objects. The save caused the query monitored by an NSFetchedResultsController to fire (as it should). It was when NSFetchedResultsController was processing the saved ContentItem objects that the memory errors would occur.

Am I doing something illegal here? Why did this work in Swift 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

With a multi-threading Core Data app I would advise to have the entity creation convenience methods take a context as an argument. In this way you can call them from anywhere and even save on the spot if necessary.

```
class func createContentItem(post: Post, owner: String, 
   context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> ContentItem {

   context.performBlockAndWait() {
     let contentItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
         ContentEntity, inManagedObjectContext: context)
     // ...
     do { try context.save() } catch {}
   }
}
```

For extra safety wrap your operations in a separate block as shown.